# Importing Large csv (175 GB) to MySQL Server with Unusual Delimeters

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, csv, heidisql

I have a 175 GB csv that I am trying to pull into MySQL.

The table is set up and formatted.

The problem is, the csv uses unorthodox delimeters and line seperators (both are 3 character strings, @%@ and @^@).

After a lot of trial and error I was able to get the process to start in HeidiSQL, but it would freeze up and never actually populate any data.

I would ideally like to use Python, but the parser only accepts 1-character line separators, making this tricky.

Does anyone have any tips on getting this to work?

Comment: "Does anyone have any tips on getting this to work?" You need to program your own parser to handle this.

Comment: can you upload the file to the database server? The LOAD-DATA-INFILE syntax as shown on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html has no limitations to the delimeters, so @%@ should work anyway.
I would not try to upload this much of data from a remote location using a tool like HeidiSQL

Comment: if i understand the question correctly the topicstarters CSV contains two separators. @IvoP `@%@ ` and `@^@` MySQL's LOAD DATA clause can't handle two at the same time..

Comment: My reading of the spec:  `@%@` is the *field* separator, and `@^@` is the *line* separator.

Answer (score 4):

MySQL `LOAD DATA` statement will process a csv file with multiple character delimiters

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

I'd expect something like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/dir/my_wonky.csv' 
INTO TABLE my_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '@%@'
LINES TERMINATED BY '@^@'
( col1 
, col2
, col3
)
```

I'd use a very small subset of the .csv file and do the load into a test table, just to get it working, make necessary adjustments, verify the results.

I would also want to break up the load into more manageable chunks, and avoid blowing out rollback space in the ibdata1 file. I would use something like `pt-fifo-split` (part of the Percona toolkit) to break the file up into a series of separate loads, but unfortunately, `pt-fifo-split` doesn't provide a way to specify the line delimiter character(s).  To make use of that, we'd have to pre-process the file, to replace existing new line characters, and replace the line delimiter `@^@` with new line characters.

(If I had to load the whole file in a single shot, I'd do that into a MyISAM table, and not an InnoDB table, as a staging table. And I'd have a separate process that copied rows (in reasonably sized chunks) from the MyISAM staging table into the InnoDB table.)

Comment: replacing @^@ with a real new line could be done with sed:
`sed 's/|@^@|/\n/g' test.txt

Comment: @IvoP: We'd also want to encode any real new line characters in the file, before we replace the line delimiters with newline characters. Or at least verify that there aren't any newline characters. (There must be a reason that the delimiter is not a new line character ... most likely explanation for that is that we are expecting new line characters in the data.)

Comment: Thank you very much spender! You saved me a lot of headache with pt-fifo-split... I wasn't unable to import a dump of 1.000.000.000 records because Percona just crash at 150.000.000... The data was in MyISAM in the previous db, and work just okey, but with InnoDB is another story... Thank you, you saved my neck!